# Async wizard - how to go back a step

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm using the `async` JS library from caolan to make a wizard. On the UI the next button triggers an event which eventually invokes the async to move to the next step.

This works great for going forward (next >>) but now I'm trying to implement a feature to go backwards.

```
async.eachSeries(this.wiz.steps, function(item, callback) {
  //do stuff
  //when done 
  callback()
}
```

But now I'm confused as to go about handling a backwards event.

Comment: what are you confused about?

Comment: Well at the minute I have an array. This array contains my steps. Doing an advancement moves the iterator to the next element in the array. That's fine - that behaves as a 'next'. What I'm confused about is going back a step. I'm not sure how to move the iterator backwards. To display the previous step.

Comment: Anyone got any ideas about moving the pointer backwards?